# Как использовать SAX-парсер для сохранения только дочерних элементов и хранение их в коллекции?

Tags: java, android, xml, парсер, sax

Есть xml файл:

```
<shop>
    <department number= "1" name="unknown">
        <product id="1"/>
        <product id="2"/>
        <product id="3"/>
    </department>
    <department number= "2" name="unknown">
        <product id="4"/>
        <product id="5"/>
        <product id="6"/>
    </department>
    <department number= "3" name="unknown">
        <.../>
    </department>
</shop>
```

Для сохранения информации при парсинге я создал класс `Department` и коллекцию `ArrayList<Department>`, чтобы эти классы там хранить. Сам класс выглядит так:

```
class Department {
    String number;
    String name;
    ArrayList<Integer> productId = new ArrayList<>(); // коллекция для хранения аттрибутов product id
    //конструктор
    public Department(String n, String na, ArrayList<Integer> pr) {
        this.number = n;
        this.name = na;
        this.productId = pr;
    }
}
```

Как мне организовать работу парсера чтобы в каждый экземпляр класса `Departament` попадали только его дочерние теги product id и помещались в конкретный `ArrayList<Integer>`?